# Multiple page PHP form elements not being updated in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, insert

I've read lots of pages but all seem to say different things and are not direct to my question. I am fairly new at using PHP and MySQL.

I am using PHP sessions for a 3 page form and want to insert the form data into my database. My sessions for the form pages are working in printing the results, however, only the last page's data is being entered into the database. I find no errors except when trying to use mysql_real_escape_string, which will be my next step/challenge – but I want to ensure I have the form working with the database properly first, so that I can understand where my errors are coming from without being overwhelmed.

Here is my code:

form1.php

```
<form method="post" action="form2.php">
    <p>Name: 
    <input type="text" name="name">
    </p>
    <p>Email address
  <input type="text" name="emailaddress">
      <input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">
    </p>
</form>
```

form2.php

```
<?php
//start the session
session_start();
?>

<?php

// defining variables
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;
$_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $emailaddress;

//store posted values in the session variables
$_SESSION['name'] = $_POST['name'];
$_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $_POST['emailaddress'];

?>

<form method="post" action="form3.php">
  <p>Male
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">
    Female
  <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">
  </p>
  <p>Age:
    <input type="text" name="age">
  </p>
  <p>Location: 
    <input type="text" name="location">

    <input type="submit" value="Go To Step 3">
  </p>
</form>
```

form3.php

```
    <?php
    //start the session
    session_start();
    ?>
    <?php

    // defining variables
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $gender;
    $_SESSION['age'] = $age;
    $_SESSION['location'] = $location;

    //store posted values in the session variables
    $_SESSION['gender'] = $_POST['gender'];
    $_SESSION['age'] = $_POST['age'];
    $_SESSION['location'] = $_POST['location'];

    ?>

    <form method="post" action="pageprocess.php">
      <p>Employment status:
      <input type="text" name="employmentstatus">
      </p>
      <p>Hobbies:
        <input type="text" name="hobbies">
        <input type="submit" value="Finish">
      </p>
    </form>
```

pageprocess.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();

    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $name = $_SESSION['name'];
    $emailaddress = $_SESSION['emailaddress'];
    $gender = $_SESSION['gender'];
    $age = $_SESSION['age'];
    $location = $_SESSION['location'] ;
    $employment_status = $_SESSION['employmentstatus'];
    $hobbies = $_SESSION['hobbies'];

    ?>

    <?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databasename");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
      {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

    $sql="INSERT INTO userinfo (
            userid,
            name,
            emailaddress,
            gender,
            age,
            location,
            employmentstatus,
            hobbies
    )
    VALUES
    (       '" . $_POST[userid] . "',
            '" . $_POST[name] . "',
            '" . $_POST[emailaddress] . "',
            '" . $_POST[gender] . "',
            '" . $_POST[age] . "',
            '" . $_POST[location] . "',
            '" . $_POST[employmentstatus] . "',
            '" . $_POST[hobbies] . "'
    )";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
      {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
      }
    echo "1 record added";

    mysqli_close($con);
    ?>
```

There is a lot of conflicting information out there and I need some clarity.

Comment: What is that 'defining variables'? You are defining session variables with empty variables?

Comment: Misinformation I read online that I will not be using again. Thank you for your response.

Comment: Note this code appears to contain **serious SQL injection vulnerabilities**. Do not use this code.

Answer (score 1):

In the values they need to be the variables you have set from the $_SESSION, not the $_POST

```
 "VALUES
(       '" . $userid . "',
        '" . $name . "',
        '" . $emailaddress . "',
        '" . $gender . "',
        '" . $age . "',
        '" . $location . "',
        '" . $employment_status . "',
        '" . $hobbies . "'
)";
```

Also why are you defining the session variables? You don't need to do that. :)

Comment: Thank you, that did help! I read about defining the variables online, and also the variables from the $_POST - there is a lot of misinformation out there. I followed your instructions and found success, but the data from the last page didn't store. I tried using $_POST['hobbies'];
after my $hobbies = $_SESSION['hobbies']; and same for employment status in pageprocess.php and this seemed to work. I hope it is acceptable practice. Thank you for your help again :)

Comment: dpDesignz,  how would he assign values to the session variables if he doesn't define them?

Comment: @bart2puck they don't need to be defined first. There is no difference defining them from a $_POST than a variable.

Comment: ah, i think we said the same thing, just differently :)

Comment: @bart2puck yea I just wasn't very clear. :). You summed it up good. I like your foreach function too. Very cool

Comment: @user3267724 You can see mine and bart2pucks information coded at http://pastebin.com/yM89T5GX. Don't forget to accept the answer if it was correct.

Answer (score 0):

one thing i do is the following:

```
 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
 {
      $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
 }
this will take each post and assign it automatically instead of you defining whats already defined.
```

this part is problematic:

```
 // defining variables
 $_SESSION['name'] = $name;
 $_SESSION['emailaddress'] = $emailaddress;
```

those variables are empty. and then next lines you set them...

you never set the employmentstatus variable in the session array anywhere.

on pageprocess.php  your values are POST values,  those are empty.  you should be using the session variables you set earlier.  you also need to look into prevent mysql injection.

Comment: Thank you for your  reply and input. I will be looking into preventing MySQL injection as my next step, I understand this is of utmost importance. I just wanted to ensure I had the form in a working state - which I know from reading elsewhere is not the best practise, even if it is not a usable form yet - before I moved on. I wanted to take it step by step as I find this helps me understand more effectively. Thank you again.